# How to let images added above each other when dropped by changing the CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, drag-and-drop, draggable, qualtrics

I'm customizing the CSS for a survey in Qualtrics. I use a Drag and Drop function with pictures. When dropped the pictures are added to a div. The images are added below each other. Is there a way to add the pictures above each other when dropped in the div by changing the CSS?

Link to [survey](https://uvasocialsciences.qualtrics.com/SE/?SID=SV_0w6HuOhw3gvc1jn&Preview=Survey&BrandID=uvasocialsciences)

Current partly customized CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
.Skin #SkinContent .PGR .DragAndDrop .Group {
    width: 10%;
}

.Skin .PGR td.itemsContainerTd {
   border-width: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
   border-style: none;
   vertical-align: top;
   padding: 5px 10px 5px 5px;
   float: left;

  }

.Skin .PGR td.groupsContainerTd {
   width: 100%;
   padding: 350px 10px 5px 5px;
   padding-bottom: 50px;
   float: none;
}

.Skin #SkinContent .RO .DND .QuestionBody ul li, .Skin #SkinContent .PGR .DragAndDrop .QuestionBody ul li {
    background-image: url("");
    background-position: 5px center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

.Skin .PGR .DragAndDrop .rank {
    }

.Skin .PGR .DragAndDrop ul {
    text-align: center;
}

.Skin #SkinContent .RO .DND .QuestionBody ul li, .Skin #SkinContent .RO .RB .ChoiceStructure th, .Skin #SkinContent .TE .FORM .ChoiceStructure table td, .Skin #SkinContent .horizontalbar th.ylabel, .Skin #SkinContent .Matrix table td, .Skin #SkinContent .Matrix table th, .Skin #SkinContent .PGR .GroupNoDnd .inner, .Skin #SkinContent .PGR .GroupNoDnd h2, .Skin #SkinContent .PGR .DragAndDrop .QuestionBody ul li, .Skin #SkinContent .SBS thead th, .Skin #SkinContent .SBS td {
    padding: 0px;
}

/* DRAG AND DROP */
.Skin .RO .DND ul{
    width: 100%;
}
.Skin .RO .DND .rank{
    float:right;
    right:4px;
    top:6px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:4px 8px;
    background-color:#666666;
    color:white;
}
.Skin .RO .DND ul li.ReadableAlt
{
    border-width: 1px 0 1px 0;
    border-style: solid;
}

.Skin .RO .DND ul li img{

}
.Skin .RO .DND .QuestionBody ul li label{

}
.Skin .RO .DND ul li{
    padding:10px 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor:move;
    position:relative;
    zoom:1;
}
.Skin .RO .DND ul li:hover{
    background:#E6ECF5;
}


.Skin .RO .DND ul.NotEdited .rank{
visibility:hidden;
}

.Skin .RO .DND ul.Edited .rank,
.Skin .RO .DND ul.NotEdited li:hover .rank{
    visibility:hidden;
}

/* DND */
.Skin .PGR .DragAndDrop td.itemsContainerTd{
    height: 100%;
}
.Skin .PGR .DragAndDrop .stack td.itemsContainerTd{
    border-right: none;
}
.Skin .PGR .DragAndDrop td.groupsContainerTd{
    vertical-align: top;
}
.Skin .PGR .DragAndDrop td.groupsContainerTd div > div {
    border: 0px solid #BBB;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    min-height:150px;   
}
/* end overrides to PGR.css */

.Skin .PGR .DragAndDrop ul{
    list-style: none;
    height: 150px; /* min height for ie < 7 */
    width: 150px;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align:left;
}

html > body .Skin .PGR .DragAndDrop ul{
    height:auto;
    min-height:100px;
}
html > body .Skin .PGR .DragAndDrop .stack ul.stack{
    margin: 25px 25px 0 0;
}
html > body .Skin .PGR .DragAndDrop .stack div.Group ul.stack{
    margin-left: 20px;  /* Group Ones need left margin */
}

.Skin .PGR .DragAndDrop ul li{
    /* basequestion overrides go here */
}
.Skin .PGR .DragAndDrop ul li.stack{
    position: absolute;
}
.Skin .PGR .DragAndDrop div ul li span label img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
.Skin .PGR .DragAndDrop .stack div ul li.stack span label {
    width: 200px;
    height: 255px;
}
.Skin .PGR .DragAndDrop .stack div ul li.stack span label img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 255px;
    visibility: visible;
}
.Skin .PGR .DragAndDrop .stack .Group li.stack span.rank {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.Skin .PGR .DragAndDrop .stack div.Group ul li span img {
    width: auto;
}
.Skin .PGR .DragAndDrop .stack ul li.stack {
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px solid #CCC;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.Skin .PGR .DragAndDrop .stack ul li.stack.penultimate {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.Skin .PGR .DragAndDrop .stack ul li.stack.antepenultimate {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.Skin .PGR .DragAndDrop .ProgressCounter{
    text-align: center;
}

html > body .Skin .PGR .DragAndDrop ul li{

}
.Skin .PGR .DragAndDrop ul li:hover,
.dragAndDropPGRquestion .DND ul li.over{
    border:1px solid #cccccc;
}
.Skin .PGR .DragAndDrop .Group h2,
.Skin .PGR .DragAndDrop .Items h2{
    font-size:12px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
}
.Skin .PGR .DragAndDrop .Items{
    margin: 0px;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}

.Skin .PGR .DragAndDrop .Group{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-top: 2px;
}
.Skin .PGR .DragAndDrop .Items  h2{
    padding-top:5px;
    border:none;
}
.Skin .PGR .DragAndDrop .Items ul{
    border:none;
    height:150px;
}
html>body .Skin .PGR .DragAndDrop .Items ul{
    min-height:150px;
    height:auto;
}
.Skin .PGR .DragAndDrop .Group ul,
 .Skin .PGR .DragAndDrop .Group h2,
 .Skin .PGR .DragAndDrop .Items ul,
 .Skin .PGR .DragAndDrop .Items h2{
    width:200px;
}
.Skin .PGR .DragAndDrop .Items ul li{
    /*background:transparent url(../../WRQualtricsShared/Graphics/Spacer.gif) top left;*/
    border:none;
}
.Skin .PGR .DragAndDrop .Items ul li .rank{
    display:none;
}
.Skin .PGR .DragAndDrop .QuestionBody label{
    display:block;
    zoom:1;
}
.Skin .PGR .DragAndDrop .clear{
    clear:both;
    visibility:hidden;
}

.Skin .PGR .DragAndDrop .NoColumns td.groupsContainerTd div {
    float: none;
}

.Skin .PGR .DragAndDrop .NoColumns td.groupsContainerTd div ul,
.Skin .PGR .DragAndDrop .NoColumns td.groupsContainerTd div h2 {
    width: 337px;
}
.Skin .PGR .DragAndDrop .NoColumns td.groupsContainerTd div > div {
    width: 337px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.Skin .PGR .DragAndDrop .rank{
    position:absolute;
    right:2px;
    top:3px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:1px 5px;
    background-color:#666666;
    color:white;
visibility: hidden;
}
.Skin .PGR .DragAndDrop ul li{
    padding:4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position:relative;
}

.Skin #SkinContent .PGR td.groupsContainerTd {
    padding-left: 0;
}</style>
```

Comment: How about sharing your current code?

Comment: You're trying to revert order of pictures set in HTML DOM by CSS?

Comment: A JSFiddle with the HTML **and** CSS would be helpful to illustrate your point and see what you have so far.

Comment: I want to be able to pile up the pictures and i am limited to the use of CSS because its being done in a online survey tool.

Comment: Here's a preview of the [survey](https://uvasocialsciences.qualtrics.com/SE/?SID=SV_0w6HuOhw3gvc1jn&Preview=Survey&BrandID=uvasocialsciences).

Comment: Not a preview, we just need to see a simple demo of what you have so far. Show the simple html that represents your structure, the relevant JavaScript and minimise your CSS to only that which is necessary to show your problem. Post a live demo, as suggested, help us to help you.

Comment: Oh, and what browsers do you need to support?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how images are added to the page DOM you may use pseudo-class `:first-child` for image or jQuery `.first` `.last` and position it with z-index so it'd be above.
P.S. As i can see, the site is not using jquery, so it becomes a little tricky to use javascript.